# query criteria to show records for a certain month

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have some records in a query with a column of dates. I want it to only show the records that occur in March. This link 
https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Examples-of-query-criteria-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8#bm1 shows the different types of criterion.

The one below in the table describes how to show only what occurs in a particular month:

"Contain a date that falls in a specific month (irrespective of year), such as December

```
DatePart("m", [SalesDate]) = 12
```

Returns records where the transactions took place in December of any year."

I don't know what the SalesDate means in the criteria function, and there isn't any explanation on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[SalesDate]` implied a Date/Time field named *SalesDate*. If your Date/Time field is named something else, such as *invoice_date*, substitute that name in the `DatePart` expression:

```vb
DatePart("m", [invoice_date]) = 12
```

For March instead of December invoices, use this:

```vb
DatePart("m", [invoice_date]) = 3
```

You could also use `Month()` instead of `DatePart` to get the same result:

```vb
Month([invoice_date]) = 3
```